# Duplication and horizontal translation in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to tikz, I found this code offline but have minimal experience with coding. I want to have five flasks in a row with arrows pointing in the same direction toward the flasks. Additionally, I would like to add volume measurements.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, shadings, arrows.meta}

\definecolor{tappo}{RGB}{148,154,110}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{155,210,220}

\tikzset{
    arrR/.style={-Latex},
    arrL/.style={Latex-}
}

\newcommand\flask[4][arrR]{%
\begin{scope}[shift={(#2)}]
\draw[gray] (-1.8,0) arc (180:0:1.8cm and 6mm);
\begin{scope}
\clip[rounded corners=5mm] (-.5,5) -- (-.5,3.5) -- (-1.8,.5) [sharp corners]-- (-1.8,0) arc (180:360:1.8cm and 6mm) [rounded corners=5mm]--  (1.8,.5) --  (.5,3.5) [sharp corners]-- (.5,5) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\draw[right color=tappo, left color=tappo, middle color=tappo!40] (.4,4.5) -- (.6,5.5) arc (0:180:6mm and 2mm) -- (-.4,4.5) arc (180:360:4mm and 2mm);
\draw[fill=tappo!60] (0,5.5) ellipse (6mm and 2mm);
\draw[fill=lightblue,rounded corners=5mm, fill opacity=.7] (-.5,5) -- (-.5,3.5) -- (-1.8,.5) [sharp corners]-- (-1.8,0) arc (180:360:1.8cm and 6mm) [rounded corners=5mm]--  (1.8,.5) --  (.5,3.5) [sharp corners]-- (.5,5) arc (360:180:5mm and 2mm);
\draw[fill=lightblue, opacity=.5] (.5,5) to[out=-50,in=230, looseness=2] (-.5,5) arc (180:360:5mm and 2mm);

\begin{scope}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(0,7.5)},rotate=210-(#3*.16)]
\filldraw[black] (-.2,.03) --++ (1,-.01) --++ (0,-.04) --++ (-1,-.01) --++ (0,-.08) --++ (-.05,0) --++ (0,.22) --++ (.05,0) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\draw[#1, line width=.2mm] (1.5,3.9) -- (2.5,3.9) node[right, font=\scriptsize] {#4};

\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4mm]

\end{scope}
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\flask{0,0}{0}{1 Molar};
\flask[arrL]{5,0}{130}{0.5 Molar};
\flask[arrL]{10,0}{590}{0.125 Molar};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX:SE!

In your MWE (minimal working Example) are with following code fragment drawn three flasks:

```
\flask{0,0}{0}{1 Molar};
\flask[arrL]{5,0}{130}{0.5 Molar};
\flask[arrL]{10,0}{590}{0.125 Molar};
```

If you like to have more of them, just ad more code lines with desired horizonal distance between their centers. For example:

```
\flask{0,0}{0}{1 Molar};
\flask[arrL]{5,0}{130}{0.5 Molar};
\flask[arrL]{10,0}{590}{0.125 Molar};
\flask[arrL]{15,0}{590}{0.125 Molar};
\flask[arrL]{20,0}{590}{0.125 Molar};
```

With this distance image will spill out of page. To prevent tis, you need reduce distances accordingly. For example as is done in the following WME:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, 
                shadings}

\definecolor{tappo}{RGB}{148,154,110}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{155,210,220}

\tikzset{
    arrR/.style={-Latex},
    arrL/.style={Latex-}
}

\newcommand\flask[4][arrR]{%
\begin{scope}[shift={(#2)}]
\draw[gray] (-1.8,0) arc (180:0:1.8cm and 6mm);
\begin{scope}
\clip[rounded corners=5mm] (-.5,5) -- (-.5,3.5) -- (-1.8,.5) [sharp corners] -- (-1.8,0) arc (180:360:1.8cm and 6mm) [rounded corners=5mm]--  (1.8,.5) --  (.5,3.5) [sharp corners]-- (.5,5) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\draw[right color=tappo, left color=tappo, middle color=tappo!40] (.4,4.5) -- (.6,5.5) arc (0:180:6mm and 2mm) -- (-.4,4.5) arc (180:360:4mm and 2mm);
\draw[fill=tappo!60] (0,5.5) ellipse (6mm and 2mm);
\draw[fill=lightblue,rounded corners=5mm, fill opacity=.7] (-.5,5) -- (-.5,3.5) -- (-1.8,.5) [sharp corners]-- (-1.8,0) arc (180:360:1.8cm and 6mm) [rounded corners=5mm]--  (1.8,.5) --  (.5,3.5) [sharp corners]-- (.5,5) arc (360:180:5mm and 2mm);
\draw[fill=lightblue, opacity=.5] (.5,5) to[out=-50,in=230, looseness=2] (-.5,5) arc (180:360:5mm and 2mm);

\begin{scope}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(0,7.5)},rotate=210-(#3*.16)]
\filldraw[black] (-.2,.03) --++ (1,-.01) --++ (0,-.04) --++ (-1,-.01) --++ (0,-.08) --++ (-.05,0) --++ (0,.22) --++ (.05,0) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\draw[#1, line width=.2mm] (1,3.9) -- (2,3.9) node[right, font=\scriptsize] {#4};
\end{scope}

\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\flask{0,0}{0}{1 Molar};
\flask[arrL]{4.2,0}{130}{0.5 Molar};    % <--- changed
\flask[arrL]{8.4,0}{590}{0.125 Molar};  % <--- changed
\flask[arrR]{12.6,0}{590}{0.125 Molar}; % <--- added
\flask[arrL]{16.8,0}{590}{0.125 Molar}; % <--- added

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a really nice flask! The trouble is it doesn't scale well because of `rounded corners`. And five of them won't fit on a page. So use `\scalebox` and draw the arrows using ordinary `LaTeX` commands. Note: I added some volume measurements to the flask.

[image]

I made a new command `\scaleflask` that takes one optional argument.

`\scaleflask[.3]`

`.3` is the (optional) scaling factor (default=1).

[image]

The code

```
\[
\scaleflask[.3]\xleftarrow{\textstyle1.0\Molar}
\scaleflask[.3]\xleftarrow{\textstyle0.5\Molar}
\scaleflask[.3]\xleftarrow{\textstyle0.25\Molar}
\scaleflask[.3]\xleftarrow{\textstyle0.13\Molar}
\scaleflask[.3]\xleftarrow{\textstyle0.06\Molar}
\]
```

creates the above image. Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\definecolor{tappo}{RGB}{148,154,110}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{155,210,220}

\newcommand\flask[1][1]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (-1.8,0) arc (180:0:1.8cm and 6mm);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip[rounded corners=5mm] (-.5,5) -- (-.5,3.5) -- (-1.8,.5) [sharp corners]-- 
            (-1.8,0) arc (180:360:1.8cm and 6mm) [rounded corners=5mm]--  (1.8,.5) --  
            (.5,3.5) [sharp corners]-- (.5,5) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw[right color=tappo, left color=tappo, middle color=tappo!40] (.4,4.5) -- 
        (.6,5.5) arc (0:180:6mm and 2mm) -- (-.4,4.5) arc (180:360:4mm and 2mm);
    \draw[fill=tappo!60] (0,5.5) ellipse (6mm and 2mm);
    \draw[fill=lightblue,rounded corners=5mm, fill opacity=.7] (-.5,5) -- (-.5,3.5) -- 
        (-1.8,.5) [sharp corners]-- (-1.8,0) arc (180:360:1.8cm and 6mm) [rounded corners=5mm]--  
        (1.8,.5) --  (.5,3.5) [sharp corners]-- (.5,5) arc (360:180:5mm and 2mm); 
    \draw[fill=lightblue, opacity=.5] (.5,5) to[out=-50,in=230, looseness=2] (-.5,5) arc (180:360:5mm and 2mm);
    \foreach \y[count=\n, evaluate=\n as \m using int(50*\n), evaluate=\y as \k using 18-\y^(3/2)/14] in {4,10,17,25}{
    \draw[white, thick, yshift=\y mm]([xscale=3]250:.333*\k mm) arc(250:280:\k mm and .333*\k mm)node[rotate=4, right]{\sffamily \m};}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\scaleflask}[1][1]{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{\flask}}}}
\newcommand{\Molar}{\textup{ Molar}}

\begin{document}

\[
\scaleflask[.3]\xleftarrow{\textstyle1.0\Molar}
\scaleflask[.3]\xleftarrow{\textstyle0.5\Molar}
\scaleflask[.3]\xleftarrow{\textstyle0.25\Molar}
\scaleflask[.3]\xleftarrow{\textstyle0.13\Molar}
\scaleflask[.3]\xleftarrow{\textstyle0.06\Molar}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. What about adding volume measurements to each flask, similar to a 250ml Erlenmeyer flask.

Comment: @Gauss: I edited the flask. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That is perfect.

Comment: How do I get rid of those strange arrows above each flask?

Comment: How do I increase the size of the text?

Comment: @Gauss: You might consider asking a new question to make further changes. The arrows above the flasks were included in the original so I assumed you wanted them there. I will remove them from my post. I also increased the size of the text on the flasks a bit but there's not much room to do more. To increase the size of the text over the arrows, try adding `\textstyle` to each text, e.g., `\textstyle1.0\Molar`.

Comment: Thank you the flaks look good. But maybe if it is possible to centre the flasks on the page. Because when I paste the code onto Latex the flasks are far right. How would I centre the flaks in the middle of the page?

Comment: I think centring the flaks in the middle of the page will help with adjusting the size of either text or the flask.

Comment: @Gauss: You'll have to play around with it to get it exactly how you want. If you can't figure it out, ask a new question and link to this one. Basically it's too wide to fit on one line. So you can try to reduce the scale factor to `.25` and go back to smaller text with `\scaleflask[.25]\xleftarrow{1.0\Molar}`, instead of `\textstyle`.

Comment: I fixed the spacing issue. However, I would like to increase the size of the text and the number. But when I write ```\Huge``` in front of ``` \textstyle``` only the word Molar increases. How do I increase the number as well?